# подключение к localhost через браузер по websocket python

Tags: javascript, python, сервер, websocket, localhost

Не могу решить проблему: есть серверная часть websocet реализованная на python и клиентская часть на JS. Все работает при отдельном запуске сервера и запуске html страницы, но при попытке открыть браузер и забить туда выделенный localhost пишет следующее:

> Failed to open a WebSocket connection: invalid Connection header:
>   keep-alive.
>
> You cannot access a WebSocket server directly with a browser. You need
>   a WebSocket client.

в python запускаю вот так

```
start_server = websockets.serve(counter, "192.168.1.85", 8081)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

дальше ввожу в хроме 192.168.1.85:8081 и выдает ту штуку, что делать помогите

Comment: Протокол Websocket и протокол HTTP с которым работает браузер это разные вещи.

Comment: да я понимаю, у меня в JS переменная объявлена так: websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.85:8081/"); то есть я пытаюсь подключиться не через http, а через websocket: ws://192.168.1.85:8081/ и получаю Веб-страница по адресу ws://192.168.1.85:8081/, возможно, временно недоступна или постоянно перемещена по новому адресу